# Not able to convert String to date using to_date() java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01861

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to update table where my input Date is of string type

```
  SELECT FromDate FROM MyTbl where NUM=3;
    *output:*

    FromDate 
------------------------- 
  24-APR-16   

 UPDATE MyTbl SET FLAG='Y' WHERE FromDate=to_date(2016-04-24 00:00:00.0)

   String FromDate= 2016-04-24 00:00:00.0

SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

Comment: It looks like you are using Java but it would be helpful to post the code you're using.  The `update` statement you posted is missing the quotes around the string value.  I'm not sure whether that is because you are dynamically assembling the SQL statement in Java and neglected to add the single quotes or because you are using bind variables in your Java and you just made an error transcribing what the statement would look like with a literal.  Additionally, your `to_date` call needs a format mask unless the string happens to match your session's `nls_date_format`.

Answer (score 0):

`to_date()` expects a string constant and strings are put into single quotes in SQL. You also need to supply a format mask:

```
UPDATE MyTbl SET FLAG='Y' 
   WHERE FromDate=to_date('2016-04-24 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

See the manual for more details:

- [String literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218)
- [to_date() function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle `date` types only have a resolution to the second.  If you want to retain information about milliseconds, then consider using a `timestamp` and casting to a `date`:

```
UPDATE MyTbl
SET FLAG='Y'
WHERE FromDate = CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-04-24 00:00:00.0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF1') AS DATE)
```

If you really want to retain millisecond precision, then consider changing the `FromDate` column to `timestamp`.